Формирование XML в T SQL
Надо сделать с запросе MS SQL вывод XML файла определенной схемы.
Примерно такая схема должна получаться:
<items>
 <item>
  <value1></value1>
  <value2></value2>
  <item>
    <value3></value3>
    <value4>
     <item>
      <value5>
      </value5>
     </item>
    </value4>
  </item>
 </item>
</items>

У меня получается вывести только такую схему:
<items>
 <item>
  <value1></value1>
  <value2></value2>
  <value3></value3>
  <value4></value4>
  <value5></value5>
 </item>
</items>

valueX - это столбцы
Что я делал
В конце SQL запроса добавлял:
"for xml path('item'), root('items')"
"for xml explicit" -- но тут намучился с тегами, + делал не так как надо в схеме <value1 = "X">
В какую сторону копнуть лучше и что использовать ( нужен чистый T SQL).

Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.
Все в рамках вопроса как текст, без картинок.

Попробуйте такой код:
select
    value1,
    value2,
    value3 as "item/value3",
    value4 as "item/value4",
    value5 as "item/value4/item/value5"
from t
for xml path ('item'), root('items');

Схема, конечно, странная. Как из получившегося xml извлекать значение value4 на клиенте?.. Неудобно.
